# Using JavaScript to build HTML datalist works in FireFox but Incorrect results in Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to populate an HTML datalist of claims with the values in a selected array by map number. I have an action button on the form and the JavaScript is a function. It works perfect in FireFox and returns the claims in the array for the map selected. Chrome gives an incorrect datalist of claims.

Selecting Map 2 gives the correct list in FireFox: Ceedee #1 and Ceedee #2. Chrome gives Ceedee #1 and Ceedee #2 but also the first three claims for Map 3. Selecting Map 1 in Chrome gives the Map 1 claims but also the first two claims for Map 3 and the first claim for Map 2. There is a line displayed in the list after the correct claims.
This is Windows 10. Thanks for your help!

```
    <!--HTML form for the map selection, function button, and claims list:-->
    <div class="formRow">
    <label for="theMap">The claim was on which map? *</label>
    <fieldset>
    <input name="map" id="theMap" type="text" placeholder="Select Map Number" required list="mapList" />
    <datalist id="mapList">
    <option value="1" >
    <option value="2" >
    <option value="3" >
    </datalist>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="claimRow">
    <fieldset>
    <input type="button" name="findClaims" value="After selecting a map, click to get the claims list for the map" onclick="getClaims(this.form)">
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="claimRow">
    <label for="theClaim">Which claim did you visit?</label>
    <fieldset>
    <input name="claim" id="theClaim" type="text" placeholder="Select claim name" list="claimsList" />
    <datalist id="claimsList" >
    </datalist>
    </fieldset>
    </div>

    <script>
    function getClaims (form) {   // Runs when the button is pushed on the form
    var str=''; // variable to store the options
    var claimsArray = new Array();
    var map1 = new Array("Caitlin", "Roadrunner", "More Values");
    claimsArray.push(map1);
    var map2 = new Array("Ceedee #1", "Ceedee#2");
    claimsArray.push(map2);
    var map3 = new Array("Happy Times", "Jacks Hideaway", "Renee's Best Chance", "Saddle Traps");
    claimsArray.push(map3);
    var claim = claimVisit.theMap.value;
    --claim;    // change the map number to an index value
    for (var i=0; i < claimsArray[claim].length;++i){ 
    str += '<option value="'+claimsArray[claim][i]+'" />'; // Storing options in variable
    }

    var my_list=document.getElementById("claimsList");
    my_list.innerHTML = str;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: chrome version?

Answer (score 0):

```
var claim = theMap.value;
```

claimVisit  is not used here. just the id enough

Comment: Thanks, Changed it, but still same wrong results in Chrome. OK in FireFox.

Comment: No error in console. Tried making all arrays 3 entries; Didn't help. Removed all space characters; Didn't help.

Comment: I've inspected the values in the Javascript and I looked at the updated HTML code in both FireFox and Chrome. The HTML for the datalist with the claims is exactly the same for both FireFox and Chrome. The extra choices must be recent values used that Chrome is adding to the choices. Maybe there is a way to tell Chrome not to do that. It would have to be in the HTML so that it would work for all users, not just my browser. I still need this resolved but Javascript is  not the problem. Thanks to all.

Comment: After hours and hours, all I needed was autocomplete = "off" on the input.

Comment: Your chrome version